# BasicHttpBinding with TransportWithMessageCredential and clientCredentialType="Windows"

Tags: wcf, windows-authentication, basichttpbinding

I am using this binding configuration on client and server:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
        </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

The client credentials seem to not be passed automagically (or are they?) this way like i assumed, so i need to know how to set them by myself. Will this even work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the reason for this behavior was a faulty ASP.NET 4 installation which i had to reenabled. After that it "just worked".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You have to enable **Windows Authentication** on **IIS**. Look at the below link for how to do it.

Also, I checked the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx) web site, the **key** difference between your config and at msdn is security mode

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpEndpointBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

The only difference is mode as you can see. I am not sure this would solve your problem but give it a go.

Below are the 5 possible “Security Modes” across all “Service Bindings”.

> **None** - Turns security off.
>
> **Transport** - Uses “Transport security” for mutual authentication and message protection.
>
> **Message** - Uses “Message security” for mutual authentication and message protection.
>
> **Both** - Allows you to supply settings for transport and message-level security (only MSMQ supports this).
>
> **TransportWithMessageCredential** - Credentials are passed with the message and message protection and server authentication are provided
>   by the transport layer.
>
> **TransportCredentialOnly** - Client credentials are passed with the transport layer and no message protection is applied.

Comment: I have activated Windows Auth in IIS already. I can't even add the Service Reference to the WCF service configured like this.

Comment: You would not be able to add service reference if you configure your we service to use BasicHttpBinding because by using this binding, you are actually not using SOAP. For Non Soap Based service, you can not generate meta data

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11390594/failed-to-add-a-service-service-metadata-may-not-be-accessible-make-sure-your/11392842#11392842

Comment: I have added dozens of service references using BasicHttpBinding, i really cant see the problem here.

Comment: Maybe, you was not authenticated, if you couldn't add service by using "Add service reference"? Have you added certificates for server and client?